# Save int in a function variable coming from a struct pointer using inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, struct, x86, inline-assembly

I have a struct that contains an `int` like the following:

```
typedef struct arch
{
    int size;
    unsigned char *info
} SARCH;
```

and I have a function that needs to do the following:

```
void change(SARCH *arch) {
    int n;
    n = arch-> size;
    // Do something with n
}
```

I just need to translate the assignment part to assembly. The problem is I have tried with this code and doesn't work:

ATTEMPT 1

```
void change(SARCH *arch) {
int n;

_asm {
mov [n], arch.size // THIS LINE
}

}
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
void change(SARCH *arch) {
int n;

_asm {
mov eax, arch.size
mov [n], eax // THIS LINE
}

}
```

ATTEMPT 3

```
void change(SARCH *arch) {
int n;

_asm {
movsx eax, arch.size
mov [n], eax
}

}
```

ATTEMPT 4

```
void change(SARCH *arch) {
int n;

_asm {
mov eax, arch
mov eax, [eax] arch.size
mov [n], eax // THIS LINE
}
```

}

Attempts 1, 2 and 4 don't compile because of the lines I have commented. Attempt 3 compiles and runs but doesn't saves the value correctly in `n`. Instead it saves another number, like 104 instead of 7. How can I achieve the `int` assignment?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: C does not support _methods_. You have a _function_.

Comment: Attempt 4 compiles and works here (Visual Studio 2015) once I removed the excess `e` from `move`.

Comment: @michaelWalz an assignment

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have fix the 'e' character thing, and it compiles now, the problem is that using the debugger in visual studio, I see that the contents of n is not the desired but a number like -858993460

Comment: Compile the function in C and use the disassembler to see the assembly code generated by the compiler. It works here when i compile without optimisations.

Comment: code 4 is correct. also try not use arguments with same name as struct name - `arch`.  `-858993460 == 0xcccccccc` are you init SARCH before call function ?

Comment: @RbMm yes I'm sure because I printed and also saw in the debugger the arch information.

Comment: @ravelinx - code4 is 100% correct, but I recommended you rename struct or argument name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by just doing the following

```
_asm {
    mov eax, dword ptr [data]
    mov ecx, dword ptr [eax]
    mov dword ptr [n],ecx 
}
```